# Windows Live ID Error 1017

Tags: windows-live-id

I have a web application that has been up and running for quite some time now using the Windows Live ID delegated authentication. It's been in production for a couple of months, and all of a sudden this morning, it failed with the following error:

> There's a problem with the site you are trying to share your information with. Please try again later.

The url of the error page is

> https://consent.live.com/pp700/Error.aspx?mkt=en-US&ErrorCode=1017

We require users consent to be able to see what e-mail address they used to log in. Has anybody run into this before? If so, what did you do to resolve it?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what the error actually means, but the following forum posts give some more details. Basic problem: Microsoft changed the API and didn't tell anyone, `Contact.View` should be `ContactsSync.FullSync` when using the contacts API.

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/wliddev/thread/7f0bcc69-d256-4e2d-a596-25e6318d83b5
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/wliddev/thread/7ade3e5b-8329-4dde-b08b-a98515363383